# XHR Progress Only Fires At The Start

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have some code that is designed to automatically upload an image after scaling client side. The image uploads just fine, however, the XHR progress event doesn't fire after the first time. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I am uploading a BLOB of a jpg and them assembling and saving that on the server if that might matter.

Here is my code:

```
var uploadCameraPhoto = function ( blob, filename, dataUrl ) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if ( xhr.upload ) {
     var formData = new FormData() ;
     formData.append( 'file', blob, filename ) ;

     xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
      console.log(e.loaded + ' / ' + e.total);
     } ;

     xhr.onload = function (e) {
      console.log( ( ( xhr.status === 200 ) ? 'uploaded' : ( 'error: ' + xhr.status ) ) );
     } ;

     var action = $( 'upload' ).get( 'action' ) ;

     xhr.open("POST", action, true);
     xhr.setRequestHeader("X_FILENAME", filename);
     xhr.send(formData);
    }
} ;
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
  console.log(e.loaded + ' / ' + e.total);
};
```

try:

```
function uploadProgress(e) {
  if (e.lengthComputable) {
    console.log(e.loaded / e.total);
  } else {
    console.log('Cannot compute progress.');
  }
}

xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
```

Comment: Thank you but that didn't seem to do it. It still only fires at the beginning. I had something very similar to that when I first started, and that worked. The problem arose when I switched to using a BLOB instead of the actual file.